# Blank Screen after running Lubuntu software updater..Power PC Lubuntu Install

Tags: powerpc

This is not a repeated question.. because none of the users I read have installed Lubuntu 14.04 on a PowerPC G4 Tower

I can successfully install Lubuntu 14.04
Installation goes perfect and flawless.

Now, after I am already running Lubuntu on
the PowerPC, I see the software updater.
I clicked it, ran it.
but, After it runs.. and it does with no issues.  I reboot the system and when the system comes up, I get the Lubuntu 14.04 with the dots as if it is booting, then a black screen.. nothing else.. after a few minutes.. I get the background wallpaper, but the login box is Black in the middle and it stays there for ever and never gives me anything else..

So what can i do at that point.. I tried a lot of stuff suggested including the "ctrl+alt+T" for terminal and nothing.. I even typed in the credentials as if it had come up normal, and still nothing.... how can I see which "Update" is the cause?